# Showing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2 in some test cases?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Code:

```
static void exchangeColumns(int matrix[][])
{    
    int i;
    int n = matrix[0].length;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    
        int temp = matrix[i][0];
        matrix[i][0] = matrix[i][n-1];
        matrix[i][n-1] = temp;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking the length of `matrix[0]`. That is, the length of the first row. But then you use `i` to access other rows. How do you know it has `n` rows?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong way to iterate the multi-dimensional array. Please use the following way to iterate through your array.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
        System.out.println(matrix[i][j]); // Here you can place your logic by accessing the array elements
    }
}
```